# Script is failing for multiple users

Tags: loadrunner

I have prepared script by using loadrunner tool and it is working fine for one user. But it is failing for multiple users. Observed viewstates correlation is failing for multiple users.

Later I have recorded the same script with two different users observed viewstate dynamic values are changing user wise.

For Eg: with A user - 12 viewstates generating in request
With B user - 8 viewstates generating on the same request.

Note: Those two users have the same access.

How can I handle view states as it is changing user wise.

Answer (score 0):

You correlate them.  This is a mechanical tool skill covered in training for both manual and automated variants.  Up to five different techniques are available

> Later I have recorded the same script with two different users
>   observed viewstate dynamic values are changing user wise.

Yes, this is expected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You need to correlate the dynamic values to make it work for multiple users. Each users will have their own Session ID's or other dynamic value, which is unique for them to help the server identify that particular user throughout its active session. If these dynamic values are not handled properly, multiple users will use the same ID's and the server will not authenticate the users.

You can get more information on correlation functions from the LR Function Documentation
https://admhelp.microfocus.com/vugen/en/12.60-12.63/help/function_reference/FuncRef.htm#FuncRef/web/categories/lrFuncRef_WBCAT_Corr_Funcs.htm